# errors when eclipse loading

Tags: eclipse

In my Eclipse, I see error messages coming in a window, and every project has a red X.

Here are some of the errors:

```
An internal error occurred during: "Android Library Update".
java.lang.NullPointerException
parseSdkContent failed
java.lang.NullPointerException
An internal error occurred during: "Initializing Java Tooling".
java.lang.NullPointerException
Parsing Data for android-3 failed
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Why is this?

WHAT I DID: I deleted the eclipse folder and downloadd again, and now it works properly!

Comment: I deleted the eclipse folder and downloadd again, and now it works properly!

Comment: Try this solution http://stackoverflow.com/a/11311718/310760

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error messages indicate that your Android SDK installation (outside Eclipse) is somehow corrupted. The SDK installation is in the path which you specified in Window->Preferences->Android->SDK location.

You can delete that folder (with Eclipse being closed), download a new version from http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html and run the Android SDK manager again afterwards in Eclipse (to check if there are more updates or drivers to be installed). That should fix your issues.

Your emulator devices remain untouched during this process, they are stored in a different directory.

Comment: I made this like 6-times on two different computer, but I still got error : (

Comment: Unzip it with Winzip or another utility, not the native zip.