# Eclipse error on startup: 'Android LIbrary Update' has encountered

Tags: java, android, eclipse

Eclipse seems to be giving me an error on startup and I am not sure what the cause is.
As soon as eclipse launches, a dialog appears that says:

```
`Android Library Update` has encountered a problem.

An internal error occurred during:"Android Library Update".
```

Hitting the details button on the dialog yields:

```
An internal error occurred during: "Android Library Update".
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

**My dev environment:**
`Ubuntu 14.04 LTS`
`Eclipse Luna Release (4.4.0)`
`Android Developer Tools 23.0.0.1245622`
`Android SDK r22.6.2`
`Android NDK r9d`

Eclipse `.log` from my workspace for this session contains:

```
!SESSION 2014-06-30 12:18:53.660 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=4.4.0.I20140606-1215
java.version=1.7.0_55
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=linux, ARCH=x86_64, WS=gtk, NL=en_CA
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.standard.product
Command-line arguments:  -os linux -ws gtk -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.standard.product

!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 0 2014-06-30 12:19:03.275
!MESSAGE Unhandled event loop exception
!STACK 0
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ShowInMenu.getSourcePart(ShowInMenu.java:334)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ShowInMenu.fillMenu(ShowInMenu.java:182)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ShowInMenu.fill(ShowInMenu.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.MenuManager.doItemFill(MenuManager.java:780)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.MenuManager.update(MenuManager.java:861)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.MenuManager.handleAboutToShow(MenuManager.java:494)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.MenuManager.access$1(MenuManager.java:487)
    at org.eclipse.jface.action.MenuManager$2.menuShown(MenuManager.java:519)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(TypedListener.java:255)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4486)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1388)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1412)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1393)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Menu.gtk_show(Menu.java:674)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.windowProc(Widget.java:2047)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:4694)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.gtk.OS._g_main_context_iteration(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.gtk.OS.g_main_context_iteration(OS.java:2473)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3439)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$9.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1151)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1032)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:636)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:579)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:236)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:648)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:603)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1465)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1438)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.cdt.core 4 0 2014-06-30 12:19:04.406
!MESSAGE Error
!STACK 0
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.core.settings.model.CConfigurationDescriptionCache.loadData(CConfigurationDescriptionCache.java:153)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.core.settings.model.CProjectDescription.loadDatas(CProjectDescription.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.core.settings.model.xml.XmlProjectDescriptionStorage.loadProjectDescription(XmlProjectDescriptionStorage.java:500)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.core.settings.model.xml.XmlProjectDescriptionStorage.getProjectDescription(XmlProjectDescriptionStorage.java:237)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.core.settings.model.CProjectDescriptionManager.getProjectDescriptionInternal(CProjectDescriptionManager.java:436)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.core.settings.model.CProjectDescriptionManager.getProjectDescription(CProjectDescriptionManager.java:418)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.core.settings.model.CProjectDescriptionManager.getProjectDescription(CProjectDescriptionManager.java:412)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.core.settings.model.CProjectDescriptionManager.getProjectDescription(CProjectDescriptionManager.java:405)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.core.model.CProject.computeSourceRoots(CProject.java:585)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.core.model.CProject.computeChildren(CProject.java:606)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.core.model.CProject.buildStructure(CProject.java:570)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.core.model.Openable.generateInfos(Openable.java:273)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.core.model.CElement.openWhenClosed(CElement.java:427)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.core.model.CElement.getElementInfo(CElement.java:305)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.core.model.CElement.getElementInfo(CElement.java:295)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.core.model.Parent.getChildren(Parent.java:55)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.core.model.CModelManager.create(CModelManager.java:291)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.core.model.CModelManager.create(CModelManager.java:268)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.core.model.DeltaProcessor.createElement(DeltaProcessor.java:88)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.core.model.DeltaProcessor.traverseDelta(DeltaProcessor.java:454)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.core.model.DeltaProcessor.traverseDelta(DeltaProcessor.java:472)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.core.model.DeltaProcessor.processResourceDelta(DeltaProcessor.java:434)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.core.model.CModelManager.resourceChanged(CModelManager.java:904)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.NotificationManager$1.run(NotificationManager.java:291)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.NotificationManager.notify(NotificationManager.java:285)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.NotificationManager.broadcastChanges(NotificationManager.java:149)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.broadcastPostChange(Workspace.java:378)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.endOperation(Workspace.java:1498)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.AutoBuildJob.doBuild(AutoBuildJob.java:156)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.AutoBuildJob.run(AutoBuildJob.java:241)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.cdt.core 4 0 2014-06-30 12:19:04.654
!MESSAGE Error
!STACK 0
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.core.settings.model.CConfigurationDescriptionCache.loadData(CConfigurationDescriptionCache.java:153)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.core.settings.model.CProjectDescription.loadDatas(CProjectDescription.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.core.settings.model.xml.XmlProjectDescriptionStorage.loadProjectDescription(XmlProjectDescriptionStorage.java:500)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.core.settings.model.xml.XmlProjectDescriptionStorage.getProjectDescription(XmlProjectDescriptionStorage.java:237)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.core.settings.model.CProjectDescriptionManager.getProjectDescriptionInternal(CProjectDescriptionManager.java:436)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.core.settings.model.CProjectDescriptionManager.getProjectDescription(CProjectDescriptionManager.java:418)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.core.settings.model.CProjectDescriptionManager.getProjectDescription(CProjectDescriptionManager.java:412)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.core.settings.model.CProjectDescriptionManager.getProjectDescription(CProjectDescriptionManager.java:405)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.core.model.CProject.computeSourceRoots(CProject.java:585)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.core.model.CProject.computeChildren(CProject.java:606)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.core.model.CProject.buildStructure(CProject.java:570)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.core.model.Openable.generateInfos(Openable.java:273)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.core.model.CElement.openWhenClosed(CElement.java:427)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.core.model.CElement.getElementInfo(CElement.java:305)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.core.model.CElement.getElementInfo(CElement.java:295)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.core.model.Parent.getChildren(Parent.java:55)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.core.model.CModelManager.create(CModelManager.java:291)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.core.model.CModelManager.create(CModelManager.java:268)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.core.model.DeltaProcessor.createElement(DeltaProcessor.java:88)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.core.model.DeltaProcessor.traverseDelta(DeltaProcessor.java:454)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.core.model.DeltaProcessor.traverseDelta(DeltaProcessor.java:472)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.core.model.DeltaProcessor.processResourceDelta(DeltaProcessor.java:434)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.core.model.CModelManager.resourceChanged(CModelManager.java:904)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.NotificationManager$1.run(NotificationManager.java:291)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.NotificationManager.notify(NotificationManager.java:285)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.NotificationManager.broadcastChanges(NotificationManager.java:149)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.broadcastPostChange(Workspace.java:378)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.endOperation(Workspace.java:1498)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.AutoBuildJob.doBuild(AutoBuildJob.java:156)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.AutoBuildJob.run(AutoBuildJob.java:241)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.jobs 4 2 2014-06-30 12:19:05.930
!MESSAGE An internal error occurred during: "Android Library Update".
!STACK 0
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.core.settings.model.CConfigurationDescriptionCache.loadData(CConfigurationDescriptionCache.java:153)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.core.settings.model.CProjectDescription.loadDatas(CProjectDescription.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.core.settings.model.xml.XmlProjectDescriptionStorage.loadProjectDescription(XmlProjectDescriptionStorage.java:500)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.core.settings.model.xml.XmlProjectDescriptionStorage.getProjectDescription(XmlProjectDescriptionStorage.java:237)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.core.settings.model.CProjectDescriptionManager.getProjectDescriptionInternal(CProjectDescriptionManager.java:436)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.core.settings.model.CProjectDescriptionManager.getProjectDescription(CProjectDescriptionManager.java:418)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.core.settings.model.CProjectDescriptionManager.getProjectDescription(CProjectDescriptionManager.java:412)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.core.settings.model.CProjectDescriptionManager.getProjectDescription(CProjectDescriptionManager.java:405)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.core.model.CoreModel.getProjectDescription(CoreModel.java:1442)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.internal.core.CommonBuilder.isCdtProjectCreated(CommonBuilder.java:406)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.internal.core.CommonBuilder.getRule(CommonBuilder.java:1346)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.BuildManager.getRule(BuildManager.java:1127)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Project$1.run(Project.java:612)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2313)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Project.internalBuild(Project.java:597)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Project.build(Project.java:114)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.sdk.Sdk$3$1.run(Sdk.java:1379)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.event 4 0 2014-06-30 12:19:06.628
!MESSAGE Exception while dispatching event org.osgi.service.event.Event [topic=org/eclipse/e4/ui/model/application/ApplicationElement/tags/REMOVE] to handler org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.di.UIEventObjectSupplier$UIEventHandler@1fc8b35d
!STACK 0
org.eclipse.e4.core.di.InjectionException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Application does not have an active window
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute(MethodRequestor.java:62)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.di.UIEventObjectSupplier$UIEventHandler$1.run(UIEventObjectSupplier.java:56)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.syncExec(Synchronizer.java:187)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.UISynchronizer.syncExec(UISynchronizer.java:156)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.syncExec(Display.java:4622)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application$1.syncExec(E4Application.java:218)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.di.UIEventObjectSupplier$UIEventHandler.handleEvent(UIEventObjectSupplier.java:53)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventHandlerWrapper.handleEvent(EventHandlerWrapper.java:197)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventHandlerTracker.dispatchEvent(EventHandlerTracker.java:197)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventHandlerTracker.dispatchEvent(EventHandlerTracker.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventAdminImpl.dispatchEvent(EventAdminImpl.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventAdminImpl.sendEvent(EventAdminImpl.java:78)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventComponent.sendEvent(EventComponent.java:39)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.services.internal.events.EventBroker.send(EventBroker.java:81)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.UIEventPublisher.notifyChanged(UIEventPublisher.java:59)
    at org.eclipse.emf.common.notify.impl.BasicNotifierImpl.eNotify(BasicNotifierImpl.java:374)
    at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.util.EcoreEList.dispatchNotification(EcoreEList.java:249)
    at org.eclipse.emf.common.notify.impl.NotifyingListImpl.remove(NotifyingListImpl.java:725)
    at org.eclipse.emf.common.util.AbstractEList.remove(AbstractEList.java:462)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$1.handleEvent(PartRenderingEngine.java:157)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.services.internal.events.UIEventHandler$1.run(UIEventHandler.java:40)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.syncExec(Synchronizer.java:187)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.UISynchronizer.syncExec(UISynchronizer.java:156)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.syncExec(Display.java:4622)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application$1.syncExec(E4Application.java:218)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.services.internal.events.UIEventHandler.handleEvent(UIEventHandler.java:36)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventHandlerWrapper.handleEvent(EventHandlerWrapper.java:197)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventHandlerTracker.dispatchEvent(EventHandlerTracker.java:197)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventHandlerTracker.dispatchEvent(EventHandlerTracker.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventAdminImpl.dispatchEvent(EventAdminImpl.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventAdminImpl.sendEvent(EventAdminImpl.java:78)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventComponent.sendEvent(EventComponent.java:39)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.services.internal.events.EventBroker.send(EventBroker.java:81)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.UIEventPublisher.notifyChanged(UIEventPublisher.java:59)
    at org.eclipse.emf.common.notify.impl.BasicNotifierImpl.eNotify(BasicNotifierImpl.java:374)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.model.application.ui.impl.UIElementImpl.setToBeRendered(UIElementImpl.java:303)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.addons.cleanupaddon.CleanupAddon$2.run(CleanupAddon.java:286)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(RunnableLock.java:35)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:136)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Display.java:3806)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3444)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$9.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1151)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1032)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:636)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:579)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:236)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:648)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:603)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1465)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1438)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Application does not have an active window
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ApplicationPartServiceImpl.getActiveWindowService(ApplicationPartServiceImpl.java:43)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ApplicationPartServiceImpl.requestActivation(ApplicationPartServiceImpl.java:77)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ApplicationPartServiceImpl.requestActivation(ApplicationPartServiceImpl.java:77)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.addons.minmax.MinMaxAddon.unzoom(MinMaxAddon.java:796)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.addons.minmax.MinMaxAddon.subscribeTopicTagsChanged(MinMaxAddon.java:365)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute(MethodRequestor.java:55)
    ... 66 more

!ENTRY org.eclipse.cdt.core 4 0 2014-06-30 12:19:10.554
!MESSAGE Error
!STACK 0
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.core.settings.model.CConfigurationDescriptionCache.loadData(CConfigurationDescriptionCache.java:153)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.core.settings.model.CProjectDescription.loadDatas(CProjectDescription.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.core.settings.model.xml.XmlProjectDescriptionStorage.loadProjectDescription(XmlProjectDescriptionStorage.java:500)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.core.settings.model.xml.XmlProjectDescriptionStorage.getProjectDescription(XmlProjectDescriptionStorage.java:237)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.core.settings.model.CProjectDescriptionManager.getProjectDescriptionInternal(CProjectDescriptionManager.java:436)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.core.settings.model.CProjectDescriptionManager.getProjectDescription(CProjectDescriptionManager.java:418)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.core.settings.model.CProjectDescriptionManager.getProjectDescription(CProjectDescriptionManager.java:412)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.core.settings.model.CProjectDescriptionManager.getProjectDescription(CProjectDescriptionManager.java:405)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.core.model.CProject.computeSourceRoots(CProject.java:585)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.core.model.CProject.computeChildren(CProject.java:606)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.core.model.CProject.buildStructure(CProject.java:570)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.core.model.Openable.generateInfos(Openable.java:273)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.core.model.CElement.openWhenClosed(CElement.java:427)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.core.model.CElement.getElementInfo(CElement.java:305)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.core.model.CElement.getElementInfo(CElement.java:295)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.core.model.Parent.getChildren(Parent.java:55)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.core.model.CModelManager.create(CModelManager.java:291)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.core.model.CModelManager.create(CModelManager.java:268)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.core.model.DeltaProcessor.createElement(DeltaProcessor.java:88)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.core.model.DeltaProcessor.traverseDelta(DeltaProcessor.java:454)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.core.model.DeltaProcessor.traverseDelta(DeltaProcessor.java:472)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.core.model.DeltaProcessor.processResourceDelta(DeltaProcessor.java:434)
    at org.eclipse.cdt.internal.core.model.CModelManager.resourceChanged(CModelManager.java:904)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.NotificationManager$1.run(NotificationManager.java:291)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.NotificationManager.notify(NotificationManager.java:285)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.NotificationManager.broadcastChanges(NotificationManager.java:149)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.broadcastPostChange(Workspace.java:378)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.endOperation(Workspace.java:1498)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.AutoBuildJob.doBuild(AutoBuildJob.java:156)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.events.AutoBuildJob.run(AutoBuildJob.java:241)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)
```

Any help or suggestions would be immensely appreciated. Thank you for your time :)

*Edit 1:*
My problem is fixed now. I ended up trying another SDK and the problem persisted. I ended up becoming impatient and created a new project and reimported my source. This leads me to believe that my problem may have been partially due to corrupt `.cproject` and/or `.project` files.

Answer (score 2):

This is probably a super subjective thing since the error is so generic, but a good thing to do is to check your .cproject.

I have my `.cproject` checked into version control and I noticed it contained these additions:

`<cconfiguration id="0.1230402123.1377291156">
            <storageModule buildSystemId="org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.core.configurationDataProvider" id="0.1230402123.1377291156" moduleId="org.eclipse.cdt.core.settings" name="Debug">
                <externalSettings/>
                <extensions>
                    <extension id="org.eclipse.cdt.core.VCErrorParser" point="org.eclipse.cdt.core.ErrorParser"/>
                    <extension id="org.eclipse.cdt.core.GmakeErrorParser" point="org.eclipse.cdt.core.ErrorParser"/>
                    <extension id="org.eclipse.cdt.core.CWDLocator" point="org.eclipse.cdt.core.ErrorParser"/>
                    <extension id="org.eclipse.cdt.core.GCCErrorParser" point="org.eclipse.cdt.core.ErrorParser"/>
                    <extension id="org.eclipse.cdt.core.GASErrorParser" point="org.eclipse.cdt.core.ErrorParser"/>
                    <extension id="org.eclipse.cdt.core.GLDErrorParser" point="org.eclipse.cdt.core.ErrorParser"/>
                </extensions>
            </storageModule>
            <storageModule moduleId="org.eclipse.cdt.core.externalSettings"/>
        </cconfiguration>`

Once I closed Eclipse, removed those, and restarted the error went away.
Recreating a project would do the same, but I didn't want to redo my painstakingly setup project. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

This is because a Android SDK outside of eclipse is corrupt. You should find it, delete it and download a new one at http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html 
Then you run android SDK manager afterward to make sure there are no updates.

Check this question out. It might help
[errors when eclipse loading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11089841/errors-when-eclipse-loading)